# How to search post in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

i'm new to django and i'm trying to create a search form in my index.html to search from my post and show the results in my search.html file in django but i keep getting this search error.
http://dpaste.com/03KAGY1.

please can you help me and show me a code snippet of how to fix this problem my django version is 1.11.6

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Article

def search(request):
    template = 'articles/search.html'

    query = request.GET.get('q')

    results = Article.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(movie_name__icontains=query))

    context = {'results': results}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

and this is my urls.py

```
url(r'^results/$', views.search, name="search"),
```

and this is my form

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="GET">
    <input name="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-success btn">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Pls, show the template code.

Comment: The error is not located in this view, but in a view named `articleDetails` with a code fragment that looks like: `articles = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)`. You might have given several views the same name/path.